# Raising permissions of account "dummy" when executing command from "root" as "dummy"?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sudo, root, taskwarrior

**Context:**
While trying to execute command `su a -c task` as user `dummy` when being logged (with `sudo su` in as `root` on Ubuntu 16.04, I receive the following error message:

> `root@DESKTOP-344ab:/home/dummy# su dummy -c task`
>
> `[task next] Taskwarrior does not have the correct permissions for
>   '/home/dummy/.task/pending.data'. root@DESKTOP-344ab:/home/dummy#`

Whereas when I first switch from `root` back to user with `su dummy`* and then execute `task` it runs fine. *When the `dummy` account is logged in, the following `.bashrc` file from `/home/dummy/.bashrc` is executed automatically before the user can do anything:

```
sudo -i service cron start

#get root
if [ ! -f /home/a/maintenance/getRootBool ]; then
   echo "Getting sudo rights now."
   touch /home/a/maintenance/getRootBool
   sudo -s
fi

# remove got root boolean for next time you boot up Unix
sudo rm /home/a/maintenance/getRootBool

#Start cron service
#sudo -i service cron start

#Startup taskwarrior
export TASKDDATA=/var/taskd
cd $TASKDDATA
sudo taskd config --data $TASKDDATA

taskdctl start
task sync
```

Which leads to the following "user description" in the bottom left of terminal: `root@DESKTOP-344ab:~#`. That slightly confuses me because it still says `root` even though when I `cd ~` it goes to `/home/dummy`, which seems like it has `root` permission but is still in the dummy `account`.

So I think the `sudo -s` from the `.bashrc` script raises the permissions of user `dummy` to root.

**Question:** How do I raise the permissions of the `dummy` account when executing a command as: `su dummy -c task` as user `dummy` from `root`?

**Attempts:**

1. `su dummy -c sudo task`, that indicates the usage of `sudo` is not correct, meaning I did not use valid syntax.
2. `info sudo` To inspect what the `sudo -s` exactly does in the `.bashrc` script as that appears to be the permission raising command whilst still staying within the `dummy` user. That says:

> -s, --shell
>                    Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's
>   password database entry.  If a command is specified, it
>                    is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

It mainly appears to affect shell commands, currently I am unsure whether `task` is a shell command, and if yes, how the `sudo -s` raises permission. It makes me doubt my assumption that it probably is the `sudo -s` indeed the permission raising command. I am looking further into that.

**Additionally:**

As a response to the comments below, the output of the `.bashrc` file is:

```
    * Starting periodic command scheduler cron                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ]
    Getting sudo rights now.
    touch: cannot touch '/home/dummy/maintenance/getRootBool': Permission denied
     * Starting periodic command scheduler cron                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ]
    Getting sudo rights now.
     * Starting periodic command scheduler cron                                                                                                                                                 [ OK ]

    Configuration read from /var/taskd/config

    Variable       Value
    -------------  --------------------------
    ca.cert        /var/taskd/ca.cert.pem
    client.cert    /var/taskd/client.cert.pem
    client.key     /var/taskd/client.key.pem
    confirmation   1
    debug.tls      3
    extensions     /usr/libexec/taskd
    ip.log         on
    log            /var/taskd/taskd.log
    pid.file       /var/taskd/taskd.pid
    queue.size     10
    request.limit  1048576
    root           /var/taskd
    server         0.0.0.0:53583
    server.cert    /var/taskd/server.cert.pem
    server.crl     /var/taskd/server.crl.pem
    server.key     /var/taskd/server.key.pem
    trust          strict
    verbose        1

    /usr/bin/taskdctl start: daemon started
    Syncing with myserver.com:53583

    Sync successful.  No changes.
    root@DESKTOP-344ab:/var/taskd#    test
```

Comment: `sudo -s` starts a new shell. It will temporarily suspend the execution of the `~/.bashrc` file until that shell exits.  I would avoid using `sudo` at all in a user's shell startup files.  Also, you don't execute anything as `dummy` after having done `sudo su`, you execute them as root.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you for your explanation, does that mean it is not possible to run a command as a different user while being logged in as root?

Comment: It's possible to do that, no problem, but you are showing a `.bashrc` file that belongs to an ordinary user and it starts a root shell with `sudo -s`.  This shell will just open an interactive prompt and wait for input from whoever is at the terminal.  It will not continue running the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: I think I do not understand you correctly, because after `sudo -s` the rest of the `.bashrc` is automatically executed without me doing anything. I added the output of the `.bashrc` to show it.

Comment: Sure. See how many times `cron` was started (the first part of the output)?  The `.bashrc` file is _re-running_ when the shell that `sudo -s` executes starts.  `sudo -s` _starts a new shell_, it does not change the user identity in the current shell.  Cron starts three times, probably since the permission on `/home/dummy/maintenance` does not allow `dummy` to create a file in it.  Therefore, `sudo -s` is run twice.  You now have three _nested shell sessions_.